# Change number in a word to a letter in Excel cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a formula that can make the number in a word in the cell change to a letter in a word in excel?

For example:
     P0rcupine → Porcupine.
     Parr0t → Parrot.
     B0ttle → Bottle.
     B0x → Box.

Comment: `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,0,"o")`

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,0,"o")
```

[documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBSTITUTE-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332)